# How to make amsart section titles like chapters in Book/Report?

Tags: sectioning, amsart

I want them to look like this (also in toc):
http://www.sharelatex.com/learn-scripts/images/f/f8/SectionsChaptersEx3.png

How to achieve this?

I'm sorry if this was unclear. I want titles to look like

"Kapitel 1

Title"

and to show in table of contents as "1.Title".

Standard amsart  doesn't look like this. And I don't want to use "Book" style, because then everything else breaks down.

Comment: Your question, as it is asked, is really hard to understand. Could you precisely explain what you manage to get, and what you want?

Comment: Also, please post a complete small document which people can use to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: That's the standard output with the `book` class. Use it.

Comment: you really do want a "book" class if you have chapters.  @egreg has already suggested `book`; there's also `amsbook` that is internally consistent with `amsart`, with the additional heading `\chapter`.

Comment: no, I don't want book. I hate its other features. You know, they don't have to be called "chapters", can be still called "sections". What I wanted was this heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not a perfect solution, but works in LyX in AMSART document type.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{Kapitel \thesection.}{-110pt}{\newline}

 \usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{section}
 [3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

Both packages used here have very good documentation: http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf